# Is there a native way to access older clipboard entries in linux?

Tags: linux, clipboard

I'm looking for a method that doesn't use an external clipboard manager (at most, xclip). I tried `xclip -o`, but that only gives me the latest. Is there a way to step back without a manager?

Comment: Maybe you could use this xclip script?
https://code.google.com/p/lifehacks/source/browse/xclip-history/xclip-history?spec=svnc2382339017a9110bc88f6675b1a66bcdf2e283e&r=c2382339017a9110bc88f6675b1a66bcdf2e283e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU, this is an X limitation, in that only one clipboard contents are saved. So you'll need something extra.